# PHP Firebird with Debian 8 - VestaCP

Tags: php, debian, firebird, vps, vesta

I want to get data from Firebird database with PHP. I have a VPS server and Operation System Debian 8 and main panel Vesta CP. My PHP version is PHP 5.

I found some information on web and I tried all of them but it's not happened. How can I get data from Firebird database with php?

http://php.net/manual/tr/ibase.installation.php

http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq234/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem, reinstall OS but not Debian 8 , setup Debian 9.3 and VestaCP.
So php version is 7. and on console ;

```
apt-get install php7.0-interbase
```

almost done